# nomencl+hyperref: Clickable links when entry appears in text?

Tags: hyperref, nomenclature

Is it somehow possible to create a nomenclature using the `nomencl` package in conjunction with the `hyperref` package, so that whenever a nomenclature entry appears in the main text, it is actually a clickable link to the entry in the nomenclature?

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Here, I define My Fancy Abbreviation (MFA\nomenclature{MFA}{My fancy abbreviation}).
Later on in the text, I want to use MFA, which should be a link to
the nomenclature entry.

\clearpage{}

\printnomenclature{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\nomenclature` command does not print anything in the place where it is issued. You are probably looking for a glossary entry, and that can be achieved comfortably with the `glossaries` package, not the `nomencl` package.

Answer (score 4):

Even if this thread is a bit older,  i would like to contribute.
I strongly suggest you use the glossaries package. It has the same functionality as the nomencl package and many more features, and its newer -  have a look http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries.

Comment: Maybe you can add an example.

Comment: I like that `nomencl` allows me to type in the nomenclature just after an equation, while I'm still thinking about it. It's almost the right tool for the job, just miss the `hyperref` support, which is somethig critical and makes me turn head back to `glossaries` which is too complicated. Which other packages one should consider (`glossaries-extra` is even more complicated)?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, \hyperpage{#1}}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Here, I define My Fancy Abbreviation (\hyperlink{abbr}{MFA}\nomenclature{MFA}{My fancy abbreviation}).
Later on in the text, I want to use \hyperlink{abbr}{MFA}, which should be a link to the nomenclature entry. 

\clearpage{}
\hypertarget{abbr}{\printnomenclature{}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ideally we would like a little more context, rather than code-only answers. For example, perhaps elaborate on why you use the `refpage` option of [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl). And, perhaps, you could even include an image of the output. Even if you don't have enough reputation to post images, remove the `!` from the markdown in your post - someone with edit privileges will re-insert the image.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My major problem with this solution is, that the link is only to the nomenclature itself. Ideally, I would also have imagined the links to automagickally appear, without me having to type `\hyperlink{abbr}{...}` every time.

Comment: @FlorianRubach: That isn't possible. You can define a short form but other approach are not possible.