# Add hyperlinks to glossary entries in lyx document

Tags: hyperref, lyx, nomenclature, hyperlink, nomencl

I want to have hyperlinks to my nomenclature, poining to the definition of those. For now I use the nomencl package with lyx, was a pain to set it up, should have used latex in the first place.

This is my preamble in lyx:

```
% --- Abkürzungsverzeichnis: ----------------------------
% START % Näheres siehe http://my.opera.com/timomeinen/blog/show.dml/68644
\usepackage{nomencl}
% Befehl umbenennen in abk
\let\abk\nomenclature
% Deutsche Überschrift
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
% Punkte zw. Abkürzung und Erklärung
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
% Zeilenabstände verkleinern
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
%--------------------------------------------------------
```

Can I add here some hyperrefs or do I need to use a different package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several solutions on my own:

Use nomencl with hyperlinks to the page of my nomenclature:
[Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/nomenclhyperref-clickable-links-when-entry-appears-in-text)

Use Bibtex or JabRef to create glossary: [Link](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9846)

I will use the first approach to solve this. Thank you for the help with the edit @KersouMan.